# Html "footer" div gets automatically nested in "main" div when they are not nested in code?

Tags: html, css

In my code, I have:

```
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="body">
          <div id="main">
          ...
          </div>
          <div id="footer">
          ...
          </div>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But for some reason, on the webpage, when I 'Inspect Element', it shows the 'footer' div as being nested inside the 'main' div.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe in the main div there is an unclosed tag... a typo maybe.

Comment: run your markup through a validator, it should find the issue. - http://validator.w3.org

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it. I'm using Phpstorm and it's showing that all tags are closed =/

Comment: There's some way to you show us the full code?

Comment: did you secure your css and extra html5 tags ?

Comment: The code, as shown, doesn't exhibit the problem. There's problematic HTML somewhere in your page, or JS moving things around, but we can't see any of that.

Comment: Too much confidential info to post. I'll poke around in the JS and see what I get. I can hard-code my solution if I need to.

Comment: First step: what is is value of the property 'display'..

Comment: What do you mean by confidential? PHP?

Comment: We can really only help you if you post a reproducible piece of code. You can strip out any content (text) from the code if it is confidential, that is probably not part of the issue anyway (unless you're using some exotic character set). Either it is bad markup, or you have javascript fiddling with the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Check inside your main div.  More likely than not, you are missing a closing tag somewhere in that div.

Answer (score -2):

When you put your first

```
</div>
```

in the code, you're ending the "body" div, and not the "main" div. Here is one way to solve this problem.

1:

```
<div id="body">
...
   <div id="main">
...
</div>
</div>
<div id="body">
<div id="footer">
...
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but why are there two `<div id="body">` in the document? `id` is supposed to be unique. And you are incorrect: the first `</div>` does not end the `#body` div, it ends the `#main` div.